# How is the set of all closed intervals countable?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out the answer to the problem: Show that the set of all closed intervals $[a,b]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Now I know that the interval $[0,1)$ for example is uncountable so I don't understand how the closed interval $[0,1]$ is countable. So, how can a set of them be countable? Thanks!

Comment: What is the information you need to know to know the interval ? Can you find a bijection between a countable set and the set of these intervals ?

Comment: I think it's asking you to prove that the "number" of closed intervals is countable, not that the number of points in each interval is countable.

Comment: Also, to adress your concern, $\mathbb R$ is uncountable but the set $\{\mathbb R\}$ is countable, since it has size $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Each interval has uncountably many members.  But you're not trying to count the members, you're just trying to count the intervals.  So $[0,1]$ is one interval, $[1/2, 4/5]$ is another, ...

Answer (score 2):

The set of closed intervals with rational extremes is in bijection with $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q^+$ via:
$$
[a,b] \mapsto (a,b-a)
$$
$\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q^+$ is countable because it is a subset of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Just count the left end points of $[a,b]$ i.e $a$. Now for a fixed $a$ there are countably many b's which will form $[a,b]$ as $\Bbb Q$ is countable. Now vary $a \in \Bbb Q$. So there are countable union of countable elements. Hence countable.